# In wiremock, is it possible to record cookies on the request?

Tags: java, testing, wiremock

In wiremock, is it possible to record cookies on the request?

I'd like to know if a certain cookie is set on the request that I'm performing, and would also like it to be absent.

```
 "cookies" : {
      "cookiename" : {
        "absent" : true
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In [WireMock.Net (C# .NET version)](https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net), you can define that a cookie must be absent.

```js
"Cookies": [
  {
    "Name": "cooky",
    "Matchers": [
      {
        "Name": "WildcardMatcher",
        "Pattern": "*",
        "IgnoreCase": true,
        "RejectOnMatch": true
      }
    ]
  }
],
```

Comment: I tagged the question with java, since I saw that this had been mentioned for C#. Tried doing the same in java, but couldn't get it to work.